# Lines of code that work within a while loop stop functioning when used in a function within a class

Tags: python, function, class, while-loop

So I'm trying to make a game in Python using Pygame, and for that obviously, each NPC and character requires boundaries, so I created this very basic boundary clause using if statements:

```
    if x <= 0:
        x = 0
    elif x >= 1476:
        x = 1476
    elif y <= 0:
        y = 0
    elif y >= 826:
        y = 826
```

Originally, I kept this in this while loop:

```
while not done:
screen.fill ((0, 0, 0))

for event in pygame.event.get():

    # Quit Sequence
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done = True

    # Movement
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d:
            playerX_change = 0.4
        elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
            playerX_change = -0.4
        elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
            playerY_change = -0.4
        elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
            playerY_change = 0.4
    if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
            playerX_change = 0
        elif event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
            playerY_change = 0

    # Boundaries
    main_character.boundary(playerX,playerY)
    print(playerX)

# Post Input Modification

# Main Character
main_character.blit(mcimg, playerX, playerY)
enemy_1.blit(enimg, enemy_1.x, enemy_1.y)
playerX += playerX_change
playerYdd += playerY_change
pygame.display.flip()
```

At the comment 'boundaries'. But then I realised that I would have to repeat that clause whenever I made a new NPC, so instead I decided to create a class for my NPCs and add the boundary as a function:

```
class Sentient:

    def blit (p, x, y):
        screen.blit(p, (x, y))

    def boundary  (x, y):
        if x <= 0:
            x = 0
        elif x >= 1476:
            x = 1476
        elif y <= 0:
            y = 0
        elif y >= 826:
            y = 826
```

My problem is, that whenever I run the code with the function, the function does not seem to work.  However, purely running the if statements in the while loop seem to work absolutely fine. I don't see the issue. I used a print function after the boundary function to find that variable x doesn't even change when my character goes out of bounds. I can't seem to understand what's going on. Help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: As @Carl_M points out, python class variables and methods use the self to "point to" the instance of the class.  I am sure there is more code you have for your game, and I have the impression that it might be something like a player avoiding zombies or some such :) I could also be completely wrong.
Are you using a block/rectangle shape for your characters?  There is a way to share the boundaries between players and NPCs using classes.  If so I can post an example. Thanks and welcome to SO!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of information was provided. The one thing I notice is the missing self parameter in the boundary method.

```
# Hope this minimal example code helps

# Demonstrate the if logic
x = 1000
y = -50
if x <= 0:
    x = 0
elif x >= 1476:
    x = 1476
elif y <= 0:
    y = 0
elif y >= 826:
    y = 826

print(f'{x=} {y=}')


# replicate in a class
class Sentient:
    def boundary(self, x, y):  # Add self to refer to an instance of the class
        if x <= 0:
            x = 0
        elif x >= 1476:
            x = 1476
        elif y <= 0:
            y = 0
        elif y >= 826:
            y = 826
        return x, y

demo = Sentient()  # create an instance
a ,b = demo.boundary(1000,-50)
print(f'{a=} {b=}')
```

Output: Verifies give the same x, y values the class produces the same results

```
x=1000 y=0
a=1000 b=0
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I hope the answer above helps with moving the logic into a class. Comment if additional clarification is needed.